# I got error when I download and build the sample collection master from code4fun

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I just download and trying a free toolkits for windows phone, So I just download sample collection from coding4fub and run it I got error as"Error  2   Project must have either AppxManifest item or Content item with name 'AppxManifest.xml'"Coding4Fun.Phone.TestApplication, 
How to I clear it??

I download that file through the following link.
https://github.com/eklipse2k8/coding4fun